# Delete from SQL from start of a keyword to finish of another keyword

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following lines in an SQL database, and I would like to find a query to delete from <_string> all the way up to </_string> in all the DB. Someone can help with that?

```
  <game_machine>
        <_string>
            <savedgamedata><![CDATA[{"m_sceneName":"AGF_Demoopen","m_list":[{"key":"DailyQuestsBoardLv2","sceneIndex":-1,"data":"{\"staticQuestIds\":[],\"staticQuestData\":[],\"proceduralQuests\":[],\"deletedStaticQuests\":[]}"},"{\"staticQuestIds\":[],\"staticQuestData\":[],\"proceduralQuests\":[],\"deletedStaticQuests\":[]}"}]}]]></savedgamedata>
        </_string>
</game_machine>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regexp_replace()`:

```
select regexp_replace(col, '<_string>.*</_string>', '', 1, 1, 'n')
from (select '<game_machine>
        <_string>
            <savedgamedata><![CDATA[{"m_sceneName":"AGF_Demoopen","m_list":[{"key":"DailyQuestsBoardLv2","sceneIndex":-1,"data":"{\"staticQuestIds\":[],\"staticQuestData\":[],\"proceduralQuests\":[],\"deletedStaticQuests\":[]}"},"{\"staticQuestIds\":[],\"staticQuestData\":[],\"proceduralQuests\":[],\"deletedStaticQuests\":[]}"}]}]]></savedgamedata>
        </_string>
</game_machine>' as col) t;
```

The `'n'` parameter allows the `.` to match newline characters.

Comment: Well the data inside the <_string> ..... </_string> is not always the same, so I need something to grab everything between

Comment: @DownNode . . . Huh?  This does exactly what your question asks.  It removes the portion of the string between those two keywords.

Comment: Sorry, pretty new on SQL, it seems that I do something wrong. 

I mean that inside the _string up to /_string the data is random (thousand of different columns), and I need to replace that to all of the columns.

this is the query I do to see all the columns:

SELECT xmlData FROM `tss-sql-test`.saved_games;

Which xmlData is the table I want to search inside columns and replace this
Something more specific would be pretty nice since I don't really know what I'm doing :)

Comment: Running your code I get 1 rows returned, and it's like a new row and not a manipulated one from the desired tables, so I guess somehow I need to select inside the table as well?

Comment: @DownNode . . . The `select` is the important part of the logic.  The `from` is for your table.  There is just data there to illustrate that the code works.

Comment: Ah I see, could you help me select the data from the column, but for the specific db/table (tss-sql-test.save_games and xmlData table)

tried this but doesn't work:

select regexp_replace(col, '<_string>.*</_string>', '', 1, 1, 'n')
from (select xmlData from `tss-sql-test`.saved_games as col) t;

Comment: @DownNode . . . That is whatever the column is called in your data.